# Git Pull Force to overwrite local files

Tags: git

"**Git Pull Force**", "**git reset branch to origin**" or in other words, **to pull a remote branch to overwrite a local branch**, seems to be wildly searched feature with an increasing interest despite few local declines.

And it absolutely makes sense with growing teams and ever increasing number of developers.

[image: shown is chart from Google Trends with increasing interest]

Currently, the shortest working solution is quite verbose and requires knowledge of the branch

```
git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>
```

> *edit: There is a more convenient variant `git reset --hard @{u}`.*
> *Please give credit where it is due [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72194920/git-pull-force-to-overwrite-local-files#comment127555815_72194920). More shortcuts [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).*

which is unfortunate, as typing the following is so much faster

```
git pull
```

which, however, brings its own challenges. Diverging histories, merge conflicts, etc...

---

We do have shorthands such as this

```
git push origin HEAD -u --force
```

which pushes a local branch `<branch_name>` to an origin, overwrites a remote branch with same name `<branch_name>` and sets it as it's own upstream branch.

However, there is no such `--force`/`reset` alternative to `git pull`.

---

What would be the best way to have this feature added to **git**?

---

[How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files?noredirect=1&lq=1) 6.6m views
[Reset local repository branch to be just like remote repository HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628088/reset-local-repository-branch-to-be-just-like-remote-repository-head) 4.7m views
[How do I force git pull to overwrite everything on every pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589814/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-everything-on-every-pull) 370k views
[Resolve conflicts using remote changes when pulling from Git remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785107/resolve-conflicts-using-remote-changes-when-pulling-from-git-remote) 240k views
[How to force update when doing git pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550937/how-to-force-update-when-doing-git-pull) 90k views
[Force GIT Pull without commiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317857/force-git-pull-without-commiting)
[Force a pull with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153444/force-a-pull-with-git)
[git force pull with implicit rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163377/git-force-pull-with-implicit-rebase)
[Clean up a fork and restart it from the upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646167/clean-up-a-fork-and-restart-it-from-the-upstream/9646323#9646323)
[Force git to update my local repo when pulling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644710/force-git-to-update-my-local-repo-when-pulling)
[Reset all branches of a local repo to be the same as remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019381/reset-all-branches-of-a-local-repo-to-be-the-same-as-remote?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Github - Discard all changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045269/github-discard-all-changes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: How about an alias? You could make `git p` mean what you describe. That's pretty short.

Comment: `git reset --hard @{u}` doesn’t require the branch name.

Comment: Note that "pull" means: (1) run `git fetch`; (2) run a second Git command to *combine work*. There's no "force combine", but there is "force use"; but since "pull" means *combine*, you must *stop using pull* when using "force". Do a separate fetch, then force.

Comment: @Ry- TIL about `@{u}` https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How to work with no local copies of any branches but your own

I'm going to take a different approach, by challenging the premises of the question. If you find yourself having to adjust your local branch to match the remote branch, this suggests that *you should never have had a local branch to start with*.

Instead, work in such a way that the branch you work with *is* the remote tracking branch, and so there is nothing to adjust.

Take, for example, me. I work all day nimbly making little feature branches and pushing them to form pull requests to be merged to `main`. But I myself have *no `main`*. What do I need it for? Nothing!

- To start a feature branch, I `fetch` and then create the branch starting at `origin/main`.
- To study the state of the remote `main`, I `fetch` and then check out `origin/main`, detached.
- To review a pull request, I `fetch` and then check out `origin/yourbranch`, detached. If, during the review, the author pushes more commits to the pull request branch, I fetch and then check out `origin/yourbranch`, detached, *again*.

So the only local branches I ever have are my own feature branches — and they have *no upstream* and cannot be pulled (and don't need to be, as the only further commits in them will emanate from me).

In short, I'm suggesting that if it is genuinely true that people want to know how "to pull a remote branch to overwrite a local branch" as part of their regular workflow, this merely shows they are using Git wrong to begin with. You should never make a local branch unless:

- You are going to add commits to it and push it, or
- You are going to merge into it locally, which is not generally the case in today's world of pull requests, or
- It is purely local and experimental, ie you're just trying a possible line of approach while developing a feature.

None of those scenarios will *ever* involve a corresponding remote tracking branch, so the situation posited in the question will never arise.

Comment: Damn, doing a detached checkout during code reviews might be exactly what I am looking for! The issue was that when I submit a code review, the author usually instantly pushes a fix and perhaps even amends / rebases / merges and asks me to check it again, while I may still continue testing out the old branch, which may even consist of small local edits. Then I want to get their state locally ASAP by discarding anything I did. `git pull` at this point would give me conflicts and a headache. I will probably set a macro that does fetch and detached checkout. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I would underline that, while you certainly mention a need that arises daily, `git` commands that forcibly *delete your work* without warning are also a source of questions, with much more damageable consequences (look for "I lost my work after `git reset --hard` / `git checkout .`, can I get it back ?" questions).

With your `pull -f` example, this would be amplified by the fact that, when you inetract with a remote, *you don't know what you are going to get* from the remote.

Based on my humble experience, I stronly suggest to take the habbit of not using `git pull` and only use `git fetch`.

Then inspect the differences with `origin/branchname`, and then choose whether you want to reset or rebase or ...

---

It would be nice to have a command to say "move to that commit and discard all changes" in one go, I'll repeat here what I suggested in a comment to [@VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72195298/86072) :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

target=$1
if [ -z "$target" ]; then
    target=HEAD
fi

set -e  # avoid going forward if one command fails ...

git stash
git restore -SW -s "$target" -- .
git reset "$target"
```

(I don't have a good alias name for that : `git goto` ?)

It would give a reasonably safe alternative to `git reset` ; the main caveat being : a file on disk, not tracked in the starting commit but tracked in `$target` will be overwritten without being saved.

You would need a more convoluted variant of `git stash` to save those files too.

---

[update] I think I found a script that manages to stash away the impacted files (and only those) :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

target=$1
if [ -z "$target" ]; then
    target=HEAD
fi

set -e  # avoid going forward if one command fails ...

list_impacted_files () {
   local target=$1

   # tracked files in the working tree that have a diff
   git diff --no-renames --name-only HEAD

   # untracked files that will be clobbered when restoring $target :
   #   * files that are present in $target but not in HEAD
   #   * and that currently exist on disk (use 'ls' to keep only those)
   # add '|| true' to ignore error code returned by 'ls' on non existing files
   git diff --no-renames --name-only --diff-filter=A HEAD "$target" |\
     xargs -r ls 2> /dev/null || true 
}

# list files as described above, and feed this list to `git stash -u`
# 'xargs -r <cmd>' avoids running <cmd> at all if stdin is empty
# in our case: don't run 'git stash -u' if no files are to be stashed ...
list_impacted_files "$target" | xargs -r git stash -u --

git restore -SW -s "$target" -- .
git reset "$target"
```

To restore back your repo to how it was :

- revert to the initial commit (using `git reset` or the script above ...)
- spot the `stash@{xx}` you want to restore in `git stash list`
- run `git stash apply --index stash@{xx}`

Comment: I don't normally do such destructive actions, however the use case I have on mind is something that I do several times a day in a team setup and that's ***"realtime code reviews"***. Typically: I submit a review and let the author know. The author then pushes a hotfix instantly, or even amends / rebases / merges and asks me to check it, while I may still continue testing out the old branch, which may even consist of small local edits. Then I want to get their branch locally ASAP by discarding anything I did. `git pull` would give me conflicts and a headache.

Comment: @Qwerty : ok, you may look into `git worktree add` which allows you to have a separate checkout of your repository on your disk

Answer (score 5):

You need at least three commands:

- a fetch, to update the remote tracking branches
- a reset to the upstream branch, using the [`@{u}` or `@{upstream}` suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56713414/6309)
- a clean to make sure no extra files are left

That is:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard @{u}
git clean -nd
```

(replace in `git clean` the `-nd` option by `-fd` to actually remove the files: I always prefer to *first preview* what a git clean will do, before actually deleting anything)

You would have to group those as an alias or a script (`git-pullreset`), that you can then call.

---

[LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72194920/git-pull-force-to-overwrite-local-files/72195298?noredirect=1#comment127556679_72195298):

```
git stash
git restore -SW -s @{u} -- .
git reset @{u}
```

> That would:
>
> - leave completely untracked files (e.g: files not tracked in HEAD nor in `@{u}`) *untouched*, and
> - would give a way to still have something to revert to "how it was before".

Comment: I would suggest : `git stash; git restore -SW -s @{u}; git reset @{u}`, which would leave completely untracked files (e.g: files not tracked in `HEAD` nor in `@{u}`) untouched, and would give a way to still have something to revert to "how it was before"

Comment: @LeGEC Good point, thank you for this proposition. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I found a caveat in my suggestion : `git stash` alone will not save files untracked in `HEAD`, and `git restore` will overwrite them. I'm trying as an exercise to write commands to also spot and save those files, and I find it surprisingly hard.

Comment: @LeGEC So... [`git stash -u`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6818797/6309)?

Comment: would somehow work, the issue being *all* the untracked files would be stashed away, and it is a known pain to restore a `stash -u` when some files reappear on disk. I was trying to list the files to stash, and run `git stash -u -- $(thelist)`.