# Git Merge takes all files into the PR after fixing conflicts

Tags: git, pull-request, git-merge-conflict

I have been looking for this, but not able to find a concrete answer which works.

Say I am working on my branch - `branchA` and I have a Pull request (PR) ongoing with it.
Some updates happen on the `master` and I need to merge those changes

Scenario 1 - No merge conflicts

```
git switch master
git pull
git switch branchA
git merge master
```

No merge conflicts, commit created automatically, all good and I push the commit. With this no files are added to my PR and the PR is clean only with my files.

Scenario 2 - With merge conflicts

```
git switch master
git pull
git switch branchA
git merge master
```

I get merge conflicts, I resolve them manually. But now the problem is, I do

```
git status
```

And I see all the files from master are `green` and I have to selectively remove all files except those files that needs to be part of my PR. Even after this I end up with untracked files, which is not good to have since I would get PR comments and I will have to do the selective file handling again when I push.

Question - After manually merging the conflicts, what are the next steps to do to push the changes that only belong to my PR ?

Comment: When I read this, my first thought was that you simply didn't realize you had to complete the merge if there are conflicts, so you just needed `git merge --continue` (or commit it manually). You have a great answer which covers this, but I thought it might be nice to have the "tl;dr" version here as well for future readers of this question. 

Comment: The thing is in many answers they miss this `git merge --continue`, and things get missed from there onwards

Comment: Note that `git merge --continue` is merely a convenience. It's nearly identical to `git commit` except that it also checks that you actually are in the middle of a merge. (I mention this in case "many other answers" might mention `git commit` instead.)

Comment: sure, but `git merge --continue` is such a clean way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I see all the files from master are green and I have to selectively remove all files except those files that needs to be part of my PR.

No, you don't. If that's what you've been doing, it's a terrible mistake and you need to stop it immediately. You're way overthinking this (or, looking at it another way, underthinking it). In fact, almost *everything* in the question is a misconception, so there's a lot to straighten out here.

#### How to merge master

To merge `master` into the feature branch `branchA`, do not switch to master and pull. In fact, I would argue, in a PR-based workflow, you should just about never need to say `pull` (and you shouldn't even have a local `master`). Instead, just stay where you are, on `branchA`, and say:

```
git fetch
get merge origin/master
```

#### How to resolve merge conflicts

Let's say you merge and you get a conflict in file *myfile.txt*. OK, stop work in Git. Whip out a text editor and open *myfile.txt*. Edit it to remove the merge conflict markers, resolving the content as desired. Save the file and close your editor. Now, in Git:

```
git add path/to/myfile.txt
```

Do that for every conflicted file. When you've done that, say:

```
git merge --continue
```

The merge will finish; you will probably be called upon to supply a commit message for the merge commit.

*NOTE:* Do *not* mess with the content of the merged files, or of the index, or of the working tree, in any other way during the merge! Doing that is called an "evil merge" and is an incredibly bad idea.

#### What to do after the merge is over

After the merge is over, just push:

```
git push origin @
```

#### What else to do

Nothing. That's all. Don't worry; the material from `master`, which is of course part of what gets merged, will *not appear in the PR* at the remote site.

That's because the "content" of the PR is obtained by doing a triple-dot diff. It consists exactly of the state of your feature branch, as a diff since the point where it diverged from `master`, but *without* any content that is already *in* master. All the stuff that comes over from `master` as part of the merge is thus "erased" from the PR's statement of what's in the PR — which is exactly what you want.

#### Last thoughts

You said:

> what are the next steps to do to push the changes that only belong to my PR

Again, that's a complete misconception. The remote site, where the PR "lives", will *describe* the "changes", because that is what humans like to know about in this situation; and it will describe them correctly. But Git does not "push changes". Git knows nothing about "changes". Git knows nothing about PRs. Git traffics in just one thing: *commits*.

A commit is not a set of changes. It is not a subset of your files. It is a *complete snapshot* of the *entire* state of *all* the tracked files in the working tree. That is all it is.

And commits are the basis of everything else you do in Git. When you merge, you merge *commits*. When you push, you push *commits*. When you fetch, you fetch *commits*. When you have a branch, it is the name of a *commit*. And so on.

Comment: To understand what Git is: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: To understand what Git merge is: https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Comment: To learn how to work correctly in a PR-based workflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72201388/341994

Comment: I just can’t thank you enough, it just changed everything for me