# How to correctly merge pull request and reconcile local repository

Tags: git, github, git-pull

When I merge a pull request on GitHub and then run `git pull -a` on the local repository I found another commit: *Merge branches 'blabla' and 'main' of github.com:repository*, and in the log, there is written: *Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.* Then I'm forced to push this commit.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a repository and commit
2. Create a branch and make some changes, then push
3. On the GitHub portal click "Create a pull request" and merge
4. On your local repository run `git pull -a` on the main branch
5. The new commit appears.
6. now you must run `git push`

The problem is that on the GitHub repository, there are Actions workflows that run when a commit is done on the *main* branch.

What is the correct workflow to do a pull request and reconcile the local repo without creating another commit?

Edit:
I'm the only person who interacts with the repo

Comment: You shouldn't get any extra merge commits if all those steps were done by you. You only get them when someone else does something remotely (in addition to you).

Comment: Try `git pull --ff-only`.

Comment: The question might be clear enough in case this might be illuminating (at least a bit): [Beginner question on "Pull is mostly evil"](https://lore.kernel.org/git/0C723FEB5B4E5642B25B451BA57E2730751C2642@S1P5DAG3C.EXCHPROD.USA.NET/)

Comment: Shouldn't the first action item (before the downvoters explain) be that you give feedback to the answer you received? Because that can be a form of clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of details about git that lead to this behavior:

1. Your local `main` branch and `origin/main` are completely independent branches.
2. `git fetch origin` downloads any changes from the `origin` repo (e.g. new commits or new branches), but it does not merge them with your local branch (i.e. your local `main` branch remains untouched). To actually see the changes on your file system, you need to check them out, e.g. using `git reset --hard origin/main`.
3. `git pull origin main` performs a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. Usually, git will perform a so-called fast-forward merge where it will simply advance your local `main` to `origin/main`, but if that's not possible for some reason, it will create a full merge commit instead.

For this reason, I am always using the following workflow and I'd recommend you do the same:

- Never use `git pull` as it might have unintended side effects.
- Instead, always use `git fetch origin` followed by `git reset --hard origin/main` (replace the branch name with whatever you are currently working on).

Alternatively, you can use a UI like GitKraken, Git Extensions or SmartGit which will visualize the current situation for you.

If you want to dig deeper, I highly suggest [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyXPFRFfXo4) that explained it to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes here:

- If you are the only person using this repo, you should not be using pull requests. Pull requests are not a Git feature; they are a GitHub feature, and are present only to facilitate collaboration. You're not collaborating so pull requests are pointless and are just complicating your life unnecessarily.
- If you do decide to use pull requests to merge into `main`, then you should not have a local `main`. You don't need it for anything, because you are never going to merge into it. If you need to start a new branch at the end of `main`, or just investigate the state of `main`, do a `git fetch` and look at `origin/main`, the remote-tracking branch. I have explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72201388/341994) how I work without a local `main`.
- Either of those suggestions would have obviated the need for this question. But if you *do* have a local `main`, you should still be following the rule: don't ever say `git pull`. It is nondeterministic in its behavior (at least from a user point of view; it has reasons for how it behaves, but it's difficult to find out what they are) and it doesn't do anything that you can't do much more cleanly by saying `git fetch` and then proceeding to merge or rebase or whatever.

Comment: Well, as a matter of fact, PRs can still be useful, even when you work on your own. In my case, even though I am the only person working on the project, I am still switching between feature branches and PRs are a great way to keep CI status in one place and allow me to review my own code before I merge it