# Force git pull on every branch

Tags: git

is there a single git command **to force a git pull** on every branch of a repo, overwriting my local branches?

I would like to avoid a bash script iterating on every remote branch and pulling the last updates...thanks in advance!

Comment: How about using the remote-tracking branches (e.g. `origin/main`) directly instead of your own? See [how to work with no local copies of any branches but your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72201388/1725151)

Comment: This is not what I've asked, thank you.

Comment: Could this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches

Comment: Are the names of your local branches identical to the remote branch names?

Comment: yes, remote and local branches has the same same; @Orlyyn: yes, it seems basically my need but unfortunately they say there's no way, you need a script to concatenate together different commands :-(

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: When I know that my local branches are old and I want to update them all from remote in one single shot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your local branch names are identical to the remote branch names, you can do this to forcefully overwrite the local branches:

```
# assume we are on branch main
git checkout --detach HEAD   # permit main to be overwritten

git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*

git checkout main            # update worktree to the new state
```

This is still not just one command, but it is as close as you can get.